# How to prevent scorching and sticking when boil soy milk

Tags: cooking-time, steaming, non-stick, tofu, soymilk

So long story short, I really like making tofu at home and I have done it a lot of times. I am pretty happy with my end results, but the boiling soy milk part always bothers me.

No matter how much I stir the soy milk while boiling it, the soy milk always sticks to the bottom of the pot and burns, leaving lots of mess. I also tried the microwave method, the sticking and burning is gone, but it is very time consuming (takes 15 mins to fully cook 2-3 litres of soy milk).

So just wondering if anyone has any great method to fully cook a few litres of soy milk? Perhaps steaming it? If steaming actually works, how long can I expect it to fully cook the soy milk.

Comment: What utensil are you using for stirring? Using a utensil that will let you easily scrape the bottom of the pan as you stir might help. Try a heat-safe silicone spatula.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the soy has to come to the boil, and be held there for several minutes to deactivate enzymes.  I hear you.  I hate the clean up after making tofu.  You can certainly avoid burning by stirring and controlling the heat, but the lees will stick to the bottom and sides of the pot. I don't think there is any way around it, unless you use a non-stick vessel of some sort.  I don't have access to that, so, my solution is simply get water into the pan right after the straining, and clean as soon as possible.  A scouring pad of some sort really helps, but it takes some effort.